# Função executando antes da resposta da minha requisição

Tags: angular, http-request, angular-6, angular-routes

Em um modal eu tenho um formulário com dados que podem ser editados.
Se o usuário confirmar o update os dados são atualizados e depois ele será encaminhando a nova página.
Mas nessa nova página as informações que aparecem ainda são as antigas (antes do update). Se eu der um F5 as informações novas aparecem.

Informações antes de atualizar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Novas informações
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Informações que aparecem no primeiro momento quando confirmo a atualização.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois do F5
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código abaixo:

```
updateClonedQuote(): void {
    this.canDeactivate = false
    const updateQuote = this.cloneQuoteForm.getRawValue() as ClonedQuoteValue
    this.quoteService.updateQuote(updateQuote, this.dataClonedQuote.id)
      .subscribe(
        () => {},
        (err) => console.log(err),
        () => {
          this.modalService.dismissAll()
          this.route.navigate(['quotes-abertas/', this.dataClonedQuote.id])
        }
      )
  }
```

Comment: Adiciona o código da sua segunda página (quotes-abertas), parece que o problema está nela.

Comment: O que acontece é: quando eu abro o a url http://localhost:4200/quotes-abertas/324 uma requisição do tipo get pega as informações e preenche os campos. Quando eu faço uma cópia eu sou redirecionado automaticamente para essa nova proposta com url http://localhost:4200/quotes-abertas/325, mas o as funções dentro do ngOnInit() não são executadas novamente. Eu achei que o angular executasse essas funções novamente, mas parece que não

Answer (score 1):

Verifica se o browser não está a fazer "cache" do pedido ao servidor. Se estiver, vai retornar sempre os mesmo dados, porque o browser acha que estás a pedir exactamente da mesma informação.

Caso seja isto, podes adicionar um valor aleatório ao final do url para o browser achar que é sempre um pedido novo, como por exampo

```
// random number between 0 and 999
const version = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
const requestEndpoint = `https://endpoint.com/api/quotes?=v${version}`
```

Desta forma o pedido é sempre diference.

Comment: Eu dei uma explicação do que ocorre ali em cima.
As minhas URL's são diferentes, mas o erro persiste

Comment: ngOnInit só é executado quando é carregado o componente. Nesse caso, como não mudas de componente, o NgOnInit não volta a ser feito.
Use antes o ngAfterViewChecked(). Este método está sempre a ser chamado em loop durante a vida da view. Guarda esse Id que recebes por parametro numa variável local, e nesse método verifica se o id do url foi alterado em relação ao id que tens guardado. Caso esta condição seja verdadeira, volta a pedir a informação.

Comment: Tem alguma solução para isso?
O ngOnChanges() me resolve a vida?

Comment: Ou então podes também ver se existem alterações no url sibscrevendo o router

this.router.events.subscribe(r => ...);

Comment: Pelo que eu vi aqui o ngOnChanges somente é usados com o inbounds proportys. O que não é o meu caso.
Como eu uso esse this.router.events.subscribe? Ele da interface Route ou Router?

Comment: É do Router "import { Router } from '@angular/router';"